# Does a right inverse of a linear map, have to be a linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T be a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. Let K be a right-inverse of T. Does K have to be a linear map/transformation.

Comment: In linear algebra, yes.  In sets, no.

Comment: What is **the** right inverse of $T$? Do you think that there can be only one?

Comment: There can be Infinite.

Comment: @user10354138 Why “In linear algebra, yes”?

Comment: @JamesSmith Indeed. And therefore it makes no sense to mention **the** right inverse, right?!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos because you are working in the category of $k$-vectorspaces.  All morphisms are $k$-linear.

Comment: @user10354138 Right. I misunderstood what you wrote.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos. You are right, I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily $R^3=Vect(e_1,e_2,e_3), R^2=Vect(f_1,f_2)$, suppose $T(e_1)=f_1, T(e_2)=f_2, T(e_3)=0$, $K(xf_1+yf_2)=xe_1+ye_2+x^2e_3$.

You have $TK(xf_1+yf_2)=T(xe_1+ye_2+x^2e_3)=xf_1+yf_2$.

Answer (score 0):

When you say right-inverse, you're already taking for granted that $T$ is surjective.

Given any such surjective $T,$ take any basis $\{\vec w_1,\vec w_2\}$ for $\Bbb R^2,$ so that by surjectivity, there exist $\vec v_1,\vec v_2\in\Bbb R^3$ such that $T(\vec v_1)=\vec w_1$ and $T(\vec v_2)=\vec w_2.$ Complete $\{\vec v_1,\vec v_2\}$ to a basis $\{\vec v_1,\vec v_2,\vec v_3\}$ for $\Bbb R^3,$ so that in particular, we have $T(\vec v)=\vec 0_2$ if and only if $\vec v$ is a scalar multiple of $\vec v_3.$

The right-inverse property means that for any $x,y\in\Bbb R^2,$ we have $$(T\circ K)(x\vec w_1+y\vec w_2)=x\vec w_1+y\vec w_2\\T\bigl(K(x\vec w_1+y\vec w_2)\bigr)=xT(\vec v_1)+yT(\vec v_2)\\T\bigl(K(x\vec w_1+y\vec w_2)\bigr)=T(x\vec v_1+y\vec v_2)\\T\bigl(K(x\vec w_1+y\vec w_2)\bigr)-T(x\vec v_1+y\vec v_2)=\vec 0_2\\T\bigl(K(x\vec w_1+y\vec w_2)-(x\vec v_1+y\vec v_2)\bigr)=\vec 0_2,$$ or equivalently, that there is some $z\in\Bbb R$ (depending on $x$ and $y$) such that $$K(x\vec w_1+y\vec w_2)-(x\vec v_1+y\vec v_2)=z\vec v_3\\K(x\vec w_1+y\vec w_2)=x\vec v_1+y\vec v_2+z\vec v_3.$$

Thus, given any real-valued function $f(x,y)$ on $\Bbb R^2,$ the map $$K(x\vec w_1+y\vec w_2):=x\vec v_1+y\vec v_2+f(x,y)\vec v_3$$ is a right-inverse of $T,$ and $K$ will be linear if and only if $f$ is.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'a' and not 'the'.